# Images uploaded with Via Perl Net::FTP get corrupted

Tags: perl, sftp, net-ftp

Why am I always getting corrupted image file when uploading to FTP server? `.gif` image doesn't get corrupted, only `.jpeg`/`jpg` and `.png` get corrupted.

```
sub png{
    my $ftp=Net::FTP->new($fhost)or die &ftpErr;
    $ftp->login($hostname, $hostpass);
    my $img=$ftp->put("$file");
    $ftp->get($img);
    $ftp->quit;
    our $image="$img";
    our $shot=$window->Photo(-format=>'png',-file=>"$image");
    $window->Label(-relief=>'ridge',-image=>$shot,-width=>50,-height=>50)->pack(-anchor=>'n');
}
sub jpeg{
    my $ftp=Net::FTP->new($fhost)or die &ftpErr;
    $ftp->login($hostname, $hostpass);
    my $img=$ftp->put("$file");
    $ftp->get($img);
    $ftp->quit;
    our $image="$img";
    our $shot=$window->Photo(-format=>'jpeg',-file=>"$image");
    $window->Label(-relief=>'ridge',-image=>$shot,-width=>50,-height=>50)->pack(-anchor=>'n');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are transferring the files in the default mode, which is ASCII. This mode translates line ends. To transfer binary files use binary mode:

```
  $ftp->binary;
  $ftp->put(...);
  $ftp->get(...);
```

Comment: Make sure the `$ftp->binary` is after login

Comment: @CJ7: Binary mode should be set before the upload/download. In fact, it can be set differently for each upload/download.

Comment: But it needs to be after the username and password step.

Comment: @CJ7: Net::FTP does not set the type by its own. It might be that some FTP servers will reset any type setting done before login. To be save it is the best to set the type immediately before beginning a transfer.

Comment: @CJ17 Thank you bro. I switch on binmode after object has been created. It was big trouble cause I need to do it after login immediately.